# Check if ImageJ has an image open

Tags: java, imagej

I'm currently using the ImageJ jar (ij.jar) in a Java application that I am constructing and have managed to get everything working.  However, there is a chance that when I execute the line:

```
ImagePlus image = new ImagePlus(path);
```

(where path is a user specified path to an image), the image may not be there.  The ImageJ library will not throw an error until methods of `image` are accessed, and at that time, ImageJ will print to the console `There are no images open.` and terminate the program.  I believe that ImageJ is actually calling `System.exit()` when it prints that line since my whole application terminates -- incuding Deamon threads.

Is there a way using ImageJ to check if an image was successfully opened?  Or should I just check if the file exists by using Java's File class?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, this is a multithreaded application that may attempt to open and process many images at the same time.  The ImageJ class (`IJ`) has functions to open images, but `IJ` is a singleton class, and thus has odd behavior when multiple calls to `IJ.openImage("string")` occur at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to test whether the image was loaded successfully is to check whether the width and height of the image are both zero:

```
ImagePlus image = new ImagePlus("/non/existent");
if (image.getWidth() == 0 && image.getHeight() == 0) {
    // Then the image wasn't loaded...
}
```

I'm afraid I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe where the application exits, though, so maybe this won't work for you...